# Tcl 7.x with TLS/SSL

Tags: tcl, ssl

I know there is a TLS package for Tcl 8.x.

I cannot find any packages to do TLS/SSL on Tcl 7.x.

I would be happy to get any pointers to such an implementation.

Comment: I hope you have a good reason for using 7.*; that's very old now. It was old 10 years ago.

Comment: yeah, well, life's tough. I guess I'm the only one left using it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I could not find a package for Tcl I will be using an SSL Tunnel from http://www.stunnel.org/. I'll have the ssl tunnel listen on port 444 on the local machine and forward the requests to the target server using TLS.

I am still interested in a better solution if someone has any.

Comment: The problem is that 7.* didn't support binary data or channel transforms or … well, there's a lot of machinery under the hood that exists to make it all work transparently in modern Tcl. If you're stuck with old Tcl, you probably need to implement most of the stack yourself (or rather have a library do it, providing commands to read and write from the encrypted stream).

Comment: @DKF, yeah, you are right. I gave up on trying to compile the TLS package for Tcl 7 - too much work. I'll either use a tunnel or just simple "exec wget".